# A module's __setattr__ and __getattr__ when accessing globals

Tags: python, module

`__getattr__` and `__setattr__` works well when i get or set an object's attributes using dot notation.
How do i intercept getting and setting module global variables from inside the module?

I subclass module type:

```
from types import ModuleType
class WUserModule(ModuleType):
    def __init__(self, name):
        super().__init__(name)

    def __setattr__(self, name, value):
        if name in self.__dict__:
             super().__setattr__(name, value)
             return
        print('Set name {}, value {}'.format(name, str(value)))

    def __getattr__(self, name):
        print('Get name {}'.format(name))
```

Create an empty module and load code into it:

```
module = WUserModule('form_module')
with open('user_module.py', 'r', encoding='utf8') as f:
    exec(f.read(), module.__dict__)
```

The code loaded from `user_module.py`:

```
a=1
print(a)
```

I need somehow to intercept access to variable `a`. In loaded code there is expected access to some variables which do not exist in module `globals()` and i want to substitute requested values.

UPDATE:

The code above doesn't work as i need: access to variable `a` is not reflected by `print`.

I am using PyQt4 to write a 'platform', where other users (programmers) add forms and modules which handle interaction with these forms. The form itself is accessible in user module via 'injected' variable `form`. I want to give users possibility to access values from form widgets and a simpler way. Instead of writing `if form.myCheckbox.isChecked()` or `form.myCheckbox.setChecked(myValue)` i want to provide the a shortcut: `if myCheckbox` and `myCheckbox = myValue`, intercepting values access and making needed work in the background:

```
def __getattr__(self, name):
    formWidget = getatttr(form, name)
    if isinstance(formWidget, QLineEdit):
        formWidget.setText(value)
...
```

Comment: What is your actual question, because you seem to have answered the "How do i intercept getting and setting module global variables from inside the module?"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't.

The basic problem is that attribute overloads only work when you are accessing an attribute, specifically that means:

```
expr . ident
```

Without the dot, there can be no attribute overload.  Thus, no matter what you do, a sequence like

```
a
```

Can never invoke an attribute overload, no matter what else may equate to *the value* of `a`.

Answer (score 0):

What you're trying to do can't be done in the general case. You can't have an attribute both have a value and an attribute. You can either do `form.myCheckbox = True` and `bool(form.myCheckbox)`, *or* `form.myCheckbox.setChecked(True)` and `bool(form.myCheckbox.isChecked())`, *not* both. I mean, `form.myCheckbox` can't be `True` and a `QCheckbox` object at the same time. You could make it work for `bool`, `int` and `unicode` can be handled but inconveniently, while other types are generally impossible.

Other than that, you're confused about what `__getattr__` does. It's not called for attributes that exist, `__getattribute__` is. But using `__getattribute__` is complicated, you might want to make your checkboxes descriptors or use properties, but then you'd have to give up on modules and use classes.

P.S. Why is form a module, and not an instance of some object?

Comment: `form` is a QDialog loaded from an .ui file.
i use `__getattr__` to intercept attributes which have not been defined

Answer (score 0):

this works:

```
assignments = {}

# extending dict class
class WUserModule(dict):
    def __init__(self, dict):
        self.__dict__ = globals() | dict # to support of import statements inside exec
    def __setitem__(self, key, value):
        self.__dict__[key] = value
        print(f"new assinment {key} = {value}")
        assignments[key] = value
    def __getitem__(self, key): # without this method doesn't work - don't know why ;)
        return self.__dict__[key]

# initial values if needed
input_vars_dict={"a":0}
module = WUserModule(input_vars_dict)
with open('user_module.py', 'r', encoding='utf8') as f:
    exec(f.read(), module)

# assignments filled with all assignment that happpened
print(assignments)
```

userland module:

```
print("user_module.py")
print(a)
a=1
b=2
```

output:

```
user_module.py
0
new assinment a = 1
new assinment b = 2
{'a': 1, 'b': 2}
```