# Is it possible to change a built-in object in Python? If not, why?

Tags: python, class, overriding

I've just implemented a custom non-punctuated and purely alphabetic string object in Python 3.4:

```
from string import ascii_letters

class astr(str):

    """
    astr is a custom non-punctuated and purely alphabetic string
    that returns a string of zeros if an impure string is provided.
    """

    def __new__(self, content):
        if (lambda s: True if False not in [False for c in s if c not in ascii_letters] else False)(content):
            return str.__new__(self, content)
        else:
            return str.__new__(self, ''.join([str(0) for c in content]))

x = astr("Normalstring")
y = astr("alphanumeric7234852fsd36asd4fgh232")
z = astr("Ácçènts")

print(x)
print(y)
print(z)
```

Is it possible to "hack" the built-in object in such a way that I just use:

```
x = "Normalstring"
```

?

I'm aware that ruby allows that kind of trickery, but I'm not a Python wizard, so, perhaps there's some black magick trick that I'm not aware of that allows one to do it (Or is the __ new __ magic method the ultimate "hacking limit"?)

I'm not doing anything useful, by the way. I'm just curious.

EDIT:

My question is more specific, and more importantly, it asks why. Perhaps someone knows why the developers of Python chose to do it that way.

Comment: No, unfortunately you can not.

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/q/11024646/3385212

Comment: Sure, edit the Python source on your machine. Is it a good idea? Probably not.

Answer (score 0):

```
TypeError: can't set attributes of built-in/extension type 'str'
```

Nope.