# Assign a class to itself in python

Tags: python, class, oop

I just want to ask if I can assign an instance of a class to itself in a method.

For example, is the following valid python code?

```
class O(object):
  def __init__(self,value):
    self.value = value
  def do_something(self):
    self = O(1)
```

Does this lead to any unexpected behaviour?

Obviously, the code can be run. But when I do

```
A = O(2)
A.do_something()
A.value
```

the output is `2`, when I expect it to be `1`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`self` is *just another local variable*. You can assign something else to it just like you can assign something to any variable. To begin with, `self` points to the same object `A` points to in your example.

When you then execute `self = O(1)`, that statement *rebinds* the name `self`. It was previously referencing an instance of `O()`, and now you point it to *another, different* instance of `O()`. Those two objects are otherwise independent, doing this doesn't make anything else happen. `A` still references the first instance, `self` now references a different one.

So assigning `O(2)` to `self` doesn't do anything to the previous object that `self` pointed to. It certainly won't alter the value of the `value` attribute of that previous object. `A` still points to the first instance, where the `value` attribute is pointing to the integer `2`.

You may want to read this article on Python names, by Ned Batchelder: [*Facts and myths about Python names and values*](http://nedbatchelder.com/text/names.html), which lays out what happens when you assign something to a Python variable. `self` is nothing special here.

Comment: So short answer: I'm rebinding self to a new instance locally. So returning the inner self would lead to the desired effect but also returning a new instance.

Comment: @Dschoni: yes, and that would only then rebind `A` if you assign the return value of `do_something` back to that name: `A = A.do_something()`. Any *other references* would not follow suit. So `B = A`, then `A = A.do_something()` would leave `B` still referencing the first instance.

Comment: Perfect. No I can go back to my original, more complex question without feeling stupid. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

`self` is a local variable. So, it will make your code confusing in that method, and will prevent modifications on (or calls to) the original self object.

Comment: My question is, can I somehow override an object using one of its methods

Comment: @Dschoni: it's not clear to me what you are asking there.

Comment: @MartijnPieters: He is trying to do the equivalent of the C++ `*this = O(1)`, which calls the assignment operator for the object pointed to by `this`, and presumably changes all it's members.

Comment: @MartinBonner: yes, after further editing of the question that's clear, which is why I answered.

Comment: @Dschoni: If I have understood what you are trying to do, the answer is "No".  See http://stackoverflow.com/q/11024646/771073

Answer (score 0):

As Marcin answered, it is feasible, but it is not an advisable pattern.

Why would you like to do something like that? If you'd like instances of your class to have a settable property after instantiation, you shouldn't do it with a constructor. A simple solution for your proposal:

```
class O(object):
  def __init__(self,value):
    self.value = value
  def do_something(self):
    self.value = 1
```

There would be alternative options depending on your intentions. Perhaps a default value?

```
class O(object):
  def __init__(self,value):
    self.value = value
  def do_something(self, value=1):
    self.value = value

o = O(2)
// o.value == 2
o.do_something()
// o.value == 1
```

I think the key here is: Try to be **explicit** instead of **smart**. It may look to you that the solution you're looking for is clever, but nothing beats **clarity** when you're coding.

Comment: That's all very well if the OP's problem actually *has* just one member variable - but he has probably simplified his real problem where there are many members with complex interdependencies

Comment: Agreed, but after edit I think OP's actual problem is most likely about scopes...

Comment: Yes, my problem is a little more tricky. But I like your advice about smart and explicit.