# Perform deep copy on assignment for instances of a specific class in Python3

Tags: python, python-3.x, deep-copy

I have a class in Python which is little more than the primitive values, like `int` or `float`, see below

```
class Entry:
    def __init__(self, value, timestamp):
        self.value = value
        self.timestamp = timestamp

    def __str__(self):
        return"[v= {}, ts= {}]".format(self.value, self.timestamp)

    def __hash__(self):
        return hash(self.timestamp)


    def __eq__(self, other):
        return self.timestamp == other.timestamp

    def __le__(self, other):
        return self.timestamp <= other.timestamp

    def __lt__(self, other):
        return self.timestamp < other.timestamp

    def __ge__(self, other):
        return self.timestamp >= other.timestamp

    def __gt__(self, other):
        return self.timestamp > other.timestamp


    def __copy__(self):
        new_entry = Entry(deepcopy(self.value), self.timestamp)
        print("hi")
        return new_entry

e1 = Entry("some name", 10)
e2 = e1
e2.timestamp = 20

print(e1)
```

I want it to behave just like the primitive types as well. So when an assignment occurs, like above, the value is deep-copied, so I don't have to think about doing it manually everywhere I do assigment like this.

As you can see, I tried overriding the `__copy__` method. Unfortunely that method isn't called here. Is there another method to override? I'm pretty sure this can be accomplished in C++. Can it be done in Python too?

Comment: Not possible: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11024646/is-it-possible-to-overload-python-assignment

Comment: There *are no primitive types in Python*. The semantics of assignment are *exactly the same* for all objects in Python. Unless you want to hack the interpreter internals, you can't do this. And again, note that `int` and `float` objects are not primitive. They are full fledged objects, they simply don't expose any mutator methods.

Comment: To illustrate than nothing is primitive: note you can call methods on numeric literals, although this is a bit tricky on `int`s due to syntax: `1 .__add__(2) == 3`, `3.14.__str__()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't override the `=` assignment operator in `Python`, because it isn't a "copy" operator. Instead it binds an object to a value. You can, however, use the `copy` module, as described here: https://docs.python.org/3/library/copy.html.