# How to make a class act as two element tuple and unpack elements?

Tags: python, iterable-unpacking

Let's say I have a following piece of code

```
(x1, y1), (x2, y2) = foo()

class Bar:
    def __init__(self, x, y):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y

bar1 = Bar(x1, y1)
bar2 = Bar(x2, y2)
```

Is there any way to avoid having `x1`, `x2` etc and unpack is directly to Bar instance, e.g. like this:

```
bar1 = Bar()
bar2 = Bar()

bar1, bar2 = foo()
```

I would expect some magic method like:

```
class Bar:  
    def __init__(self):
        self.x = None
        self.y = None
    def __unpack__(self, x, y):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
```

But there is no such a method (or am I wrong?). How can I accomplish it another way?

Assume that `foo` is given and I cannot change it to return objects directly.

Comment: are you still passing x and y in the second example of `Bar()` ?

Comment: You can assign to a slice of bar (as in „mylist[:] = 1, 2, 3“) but you cannot unpack and asign in the same step-it is illdefined which elements go to „bar1“ and which go to „bar2“.

Comment: Your question is confusing. What does `bar()` do? And the question @devesh asked too.

Comment: use lambda function.

Comment: so you want to change behaviour of assignment operator

Comment: @TeshanShanukaJ `bar` is an instance of `Bar`, it is not callable

Comment: @DeveshKumarSingh I edited the question so it is more clear now.

Comment: How is `__unpack__` going to receive your x and y?

Comment: Your edit changed the behavior of foo. Does it return „x1, y1, x2, y2“ or „(x1, y1), (x2, y2)“? In the later case, you can use assignment.

Comment: You want to do something like `5=a` instead of `a=5`. That is not possible and is a wrong use of the assignment operator.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11024646/is-it-possible-to-overload-python-assignment/11024909#11024909

Answer (score 1):

Here's a way, but it's not particularly readable (I'm fond of `tuplify` though!)

```py
def tuplify(seq, tuple_len): 
    """
    Groups elements of sequence to tuples of length tuple_len
    """
    return [tuple(el for idx, el in g[1]) for g in itertools.groupby(enumerate(seq), key=lambda x: x[0]//tuple_len)]

bar1, bar2 = (Bar(*tup) for tup in tuplify(foo(), 2)))
```

Comment: but he want to write bar1, bar2 = foo()